# Flash a picture for 1 second (Fade in and out a picture)

Tags: swift, animation

I'm trying to make a picture show for 1 second then fade back to the original picture again. Here is my try;

```
@IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
var button1flashing = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


if !button1flashing {
            flashbutton1()
        } else {
            stopflashingbutton1()
        }
}


func flashbutton1() {
    button1flashing = true

    UIButton.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {

        self.button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "code1"), forState: .Normal)

        }, completion: {Bool in
    })
}


func stopflashingbutton1() {

    UIButton.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {

        self.button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "code2"), forState: .Normal)

        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Problem: The button is immediately set to the image "code1" once the View loads (without animating), even though it is set to "code2" in the Storyboard. Also, it does not fade back to the image "code2" (doesn't execute `func stopflashingbutton1`)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function (you need to show and hide the button):

```
func flashButton(button: UIButton, imageName: String, completion: (finished: Bool) -> Void) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        button.alpha = 0
        }, completion: {finished in
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName), forState: .Normal)
            UIButton.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
                button.alpha = 1
                }, completion: {finished in
                    completion(finished: finished)
            })
    })
}

func flashButton(button: UIButton, imageName: String) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        button.alpha = 0
        }, completion: {finished in
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName), forState: .Normal)
            UIButton.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
                button.alpha = 1
                })
    })
}
```

In your viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flashButton(button1, imageName: "code1") { (finished) -> Void in
            self.flashButton(self.button1, imageName: "code2")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the button needs to be visible at all time.

Answer (score 0):

set alpha to 0.1 and then to 1.0 with a sec gap in between. This gives animation effect.